# MongoDB - Geometry object to return the total pairs/points in linear ring

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geojson

I am trying to write a performance report based on shapefile data I have stored within docs stored in collections.

Here is a sample of data:

The following function works quite well as it returns the amount of bytes for each document - great, however I would also like to know how many points/pairs are stored within each polygon's linear string for each document.

```
db.getCollection("_collectionName").aggregate([{"$project": {"object_size": { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" }}}])
```

This returns the following set of data (sample):

```
  { _id: ObjectId("5ef7da26ae8659149c97657e"), rootSize: 42215 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5ef7da45ae8659149c97657f"), rootSize: 118574 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5ef7daf1ae8659149c976585"), rootSize: 11886 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5f216685dbef0f7c3339ec03"), rootSize: 43136 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5ef7daa6ae8659149c976582"), rootSize: 40823 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5f3495129861ce45eb4e9728"), rootSize: 394884 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5ef7d7f6ae8659149c97657c"), rootSize: 125309 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5ef7dad6ae8659149c976584"), rootSize: 127447 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef26538cd3bddd8389e"), rootSize: 17670 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef26538cd3bddd8389f"), rootSize: 11398 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef16538cd3bddd8389c"), rootSize: 2415 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef36538cd3bddd838ae"), rootSize: 1757 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef36538cd3bddd838b0"), rootSize: 4866 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef36538cd3bddd838a8"), rootSize: 1510 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef26538cd3bddd838a7"), rootSize: 39631 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef36538cd3bddd838ab"), rootSize: 3662 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef36538cd3bddd838aa"), rootSize: 15844 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef16538cd3bddd8389d"), rootSize: 17196 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef26538cd3bddd838a3"), rootSize: 34940 },
  { _id: ObjectId("5fa56ef36538cd3bddd838af"), rootSize: 468367 }
```

Which is great but it does not tell me how many elements are in the array/linear string within geometry.coordinates.

I have tried the following, but no cigar:

```
db.getCollection("_collectionName").aggregate([{$project: { count: { $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$geometry", [] ] } } } }])
MongoServerError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: object
```

It comes back with an error, which i understand - so i referenced the coordinates array:

```
db.getCollection("_collectionName").aggregate([{$project: { count: { $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$geometry.coordinates", [] ] } } } }])
```

Which, returned the following data, again correct, if you understand GeoJSON files this is normal as this is the top level of the linear ring, sample data:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5ef7da26ae8659149c97657e"), count: 1 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5ef7da45ae8659149c97657f"), count: 1 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5ef7daf1ae8659149c976585"), count: 1 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5f216685dbef0f7c3339ec03"), count: 1 }
```

So  I then added the top level array of 0 to my aggregate function:

```
db.getCollection("_collectionName").aggregate([{$project: { count: { $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$geometry.coordinates.0", [] ] } } } }])
```

And this is what was returned:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5ef7da26ae8659149c97657e"), count: 0 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5ef7da45ae8659149c97657f"), count: 0 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5ef7daf1ae8659149c976585"), count: 0 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5f216685dbef0f7c3339ec03"), count: 0 }
```

And that is not possible, here is a screenshot from Studio3T software:

[image: Studio3T]

Anybody who might be able to help or point me in the right direction please do so....

(I would be very grateful!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot notation won't work on array elements within an aggregation. You'll want to use the $arrayElemAt operator, as follows:

```
db.getCollection("_aGStbl").aggregate([{
    $project: {
       count: { $size: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$geometry.coordinates", 0 ]}}
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

To cater for Null values, you can use a $cond, depending on your objective for the output:

INSERT SOME DATA INTO A TESTDB:

```
db.arrayTest.insertMany([
{ _id: 1, arrayOfArrays: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] ] },
{ _id: 2, arrayOfArrays: [ [ 4, 5 ], [ 5, 6, 7 ] ] },
{ _id: 3, arrayOfArrays: [ [], [] ] },
{ _id: 4, arrayOfArrays: [ [], [], [] ] },
{ _id: 5 }
] )
{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedIds: { '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5 } }
```

TRY THESE AGGREGATE CALLS:

```
db.arrayTest.aggregate([{$project: { count: { $size: { "$ifNull": [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$arrayOfArrays", 0 ] }, [ ] ] } } } } ] )
{ _id: 1, count: 3 }
{ _id: 2, count: 2 }
{ _id: 3, count: 0 }
{ _id: 4, count: 0 }
{ _id: 5, count: 0 }

db.arrayTest.aggregate([{$project: { count: { $cond: { if: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$arrayOfArrays", 0 ]}, then: { $size: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$arrayOfArrays", 0 ] } }, else: null} } } } ] )
{ _id: 1, count: 3 }
{ _id: 2, count: 2 }
{ _id: 3, count: 0 }
{ _id: 4, count: 0 }
{ _id: 5, count: null }
```